# How to keep the rank in google search engine database when changing ip address

Tags: search-engines, web-hosting

I am a newbie in the field of website making. I currently made a website using Django and host it using digital ocean, I learn all of it by myself and I am very interested. However, I would like to learn google search engine optimization now and let people have a higher chance of visiting my website. And I wonder, because I am just testing my website status so I use Digital Ocean, what if in the near future, I change the hosting location ,and thus the ip address change, could google still keep the rank of the website when searching a particular website.

Answer (score 2):

The Google rank is related to the website domain and not to the IP.

Most of the commercial sites as social networks, newspapers, etc. are identified by its name (facebook.com, nytimes.com, ebay.com, for example) but behind that name are a lot of servers on multiple countries.

Each group of servers in the same physical place are behind a traffic balancer that have its own IP address. So for Google, the IP address means nothing, the important thing is the domain name.

Even if you change the domain name in the future, Google provides [tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en) to transfer the rank from one domain to another if the content has not changed.